# Dom Traversal with lxml into a graph database and pass on ID to establish a complete tree

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, neo4j, lxml, graph-databases

I'm inserting hierarchical data made of a DOM Tree into a graph database but, I'm not able to establish the complete relationship between the nodes. I while looping I ended up truncating the trees

Below is the code that illustrates a traversing of DOM nodes, inserting the tags and obtaining the last inserted id. The problem I'm having is how to properly connect the trees by passing the ID obtained from the previous iteration.
I had the same issue when I used a recursion.
How do I loop and pass the IDs so they can be evenly connected to all the node trees?

Considering the following HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="menu">
      <div class="itm">home</div>
      <div class="itm">About us</div>
      <div class="itm">Contact us</div>
    </ul>
    <div id="idone" class="classone">
      <li class="item1">First</li>
      <li class="item2">Second</li>
      <li class="item3">Third</li>
      <div id="innerone"><h1>This Title</h1></div>
      <div id="innertwo"><h2>Subheads</h2></div>      
    </div>
    <div id="second" class="below">
      <div class="inner">
        <h1>welcome</h1>
        <h1>another</h1>
        <h2>third</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the current python code, I ended up with the truncated tree as illustrated. I omitted the graph Database driver. in order to focus on the cypher since most graph database follows almost the same cypher query.

```
import json
from lxml import etree
from itertools import tee
from lxml import html
for n in dom_tree.iter():
        cursor = Cypher("CREATE (t:node {tag: %s} ) RETURN id(t)", params=(n.tag,))
    
        parent_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]  # get last inserted ID
        ag.commit()
        print(f"Parent:{n.tag}")
        for x in n.iterchildren():
            cursor = Cypher("CREATE (x:node {tag: %s} ) RETURN id(x)", params=(x.tag,))
            xid = cursor.fetchone()[0]  # get last inserted ID
            ag.commit()
            print(f"--------{x.tag}")
            cx = Cypher("MATCH (p:node),(k:node) WHERE id(p) = %s AND id(k) = %s CREATE (p)-[:connect {name: p.name+ '->'+k.name}]->(k)", params=(eid, xid,))
```

[image: the node trees are scattered instead of linked]

Answer (score 1):

`ElementTree` provides a method, `getiterator()`, to iterate over every element in the tree.

As you visit each node, you can also get a list of its children with `element.getchildren()` or its parent with `element.getparent()`.

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.parse("about.html")
for element in tree.getiterator():
    if parent := element.getparent():
        print(f"The element {element.tag} with text {element.text} and attributes {element.attrib} is the child of the element {parent.tag}")
```

Comment: but how do i print out the relationship between them?

Comment: While I'm not familiar enough with Cypher to adapt this into the correct command, I've edited the answer to print the relationships between the elements.

Comment: Note that `getiterator()` is deprecated. It is available in lxml, but no longer in ElementTree (removed in Python 3.9). https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#getiterator. `getchildren()` is also deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you crate tag nodes for the parent time and again, you need to pass on the identifier for the parent node for each level down.

Either you have to take a recursive approach where you pass in the id of the parent to the function you call recursively.

Or you need to assign the elements in your dom tree an id e.g. based on level and position (sibling) to identify them uniquely.

in neo4j you can also use

```
MATCH (n) WHERE id(n) = $id
MERGE (n)-[:CHILD]->(m:Node {tag:$tag)
```

to create the child within the context of the parent but that doesn't work with duplicate tags.

I'd go with the recursive approach.

Comment: Do you have some code snippets to try pls?